# CURL -I issue stop responding when contain "="

Tags: curl, centos

i did this command :

```
curl -I 'http://criminaljustice.state.ny.us/cgi/internet/nsor/fortecgi?serviceName=WebNSOR&templateName=detail.htm&requestingHandler=WebNSORDetailHandler&ID=368343543'
```

but stuck

but if i did this :

```
curl -I 'http://criminaljustice.state.ny.us/cgi/internet/nsor/fortecgi'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 207
Content-type: text/html
Server: Sun-ONE-Web-Server/6.1
Date: Sat, 15 Dec 2012 08:49:14 GMT
Via: 1.1 proxy-internet-revproxy
Proxy-agent: Oracle-iPlanet-Proxy-Server/4.0
```

then i try shorten it :

```
curl -I 'http://criminaljustice.state.ny.us/cgi/internet/nsor/fortecgi?serviceName=WebNSOR&templateName=detail.htm'
```

stuck too

i dont know why

seems like if the url contain "=" it stop responding

so tried this url removing the "=" (serviceName=WebNSOR to serviceNameWebNSOR) :

```
curl -I 'http://criminaljustice.state.ny.us/cgi/internet/nsor/fortecgi?serviceNameWebNSOR'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 207
Content-type: text/html
Server: Sun-ONE-Web-Server/6.1
Date: Sat, 15 Dec 2012 08:50:38 GMT
Via: 1.1 proxy-internet-revproxy
Proxy-agent: Oracle-iPlanet-Proxy-Server/4.0
```

why i cant use `=` ? please assist me

Comment: please check out those formatting buttons on the input field, they'll help you make a better question. Also, use interpunction, Capital letters, the 'apostrofe' can be your friend too...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the `=` that does the problem, but the `?`.

You need to inhibit the `?` such as :

```
curl -I 'http://criminaljustice.state.ny.us/cgi/internet/nsor/fortecgi\?serviceName=WebNSOR&templateName=detail.htm'
```

Comment: hmm it works but why must use \? it never happen before, do i have to configure something to make it work using '?' only?

Comment: also if i use curl_setopt to post that url, it stuck on my php script

Comment: This is not a problem with curl, but with the request. You are requiring `HEAD` using the `-I` option, but you pass `GET` arguments after a `?`. Do you see the problem? - About your PHP script, your question do not mention it so I can't help.